# Fighting with thread close

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Does anyone can see where is the problem?

```
UserActivityHook actHook;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    actHook = new UserActivityHook();
    actHook.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(klawisze);
    actHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(klawisze2);
    actHook.Start();

}

public void pw()
{
    while (!stopIt)
    {
        SetCursorPos(576, 363);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        SetCursorPos(650, 363);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        SetCursorPos(650, 430);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }   
}
public void Stop()
{
    stopIt = true;
}
private volatile bool stopIt;

public void dw()
{
    while (!stopIt)
    {
        SetCursorPos(860, 350);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        SetCursorPos(890, 350);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        SetCursorPos(890, 380);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}

public void klawisze(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Thread w1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pw));
    Thread w2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(dw));

    try
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 21) //CTRL + SHIFT + U
        {       //1

            stopIt = false;
            w1.Start();
            if (e.KeyChar == 9)
            {
                Stop();
                w1.Join();
            }
        }
        if (e.KeyChar == 9) //CTRL + SHIFT + I
        {   //2

            stopIt = false;
            w2.Start();
            if (e.KeyChar == 21)
            {
                Stop();
                w2.Join();
            }
        }
    }
```

It should draw triangle with delays when I press 1st hotkey and draw 2nd triangle (+ stop draw 1st) when I press 2nd hotkey, but its draw 2 triangle at same time... I'm confuse...

Comment: What does "klawisze2" does? I looks like you never stop your current threads and always create new threads. Also your ifquery is impossible

Comment: This is badly broken code.  You have *two* threads that want to move the cursor, neither has a good chance to win.  The first if (e.KeyChar == 9) statement can never be true, you already checked that it is 21.  So the threads never stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of you `If`query its impossible to call `Stop()` or `Join` a thread. Instead it will start a new Thread. Also your Threads are local and you always create new ones, so you cant stop them globally

```
                if (e.KeyChar == 21) 
                {       

                    stopIt = false;
                    w1.Start();
                    if (e.KeyChar == 9) // How should this work? e.Keychar is 21 if the first query passed
                    {
                    // This will never be executed
                        Stop();
                        w1.Join();
                    }
                }
```

Edit: cause you ask

```
private static Thread w1;
private static Thread w2;

 public void klawisze(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 21) //CTRL + SHIFT + U
            {   
                if (w2 != null)
                {    
                       Stop();
                       w2.Join();
                       while (w2.IsAlive)
                       {
                              Thread.Sleep(100);
                       }
                }
                stopIt = false;
                w1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pw));
                w1.Start();
            }
            if (e.KeyChar == 9) //CTRL + SHIFT + I
            {   //2
                if (w1 != null)
                { 
                       Stop();
                       w1.Join();
                       while (w1.IsAlive)
                       {
                              Thread.Sleep(100);
                       }
                       stopIt = false;
                }
                w2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(dw));
                w2.Start();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So how can I replace it ?

Comment: @user3057699 I added a possible solution. It maybe not completly right, written on my mobile